# QGIS Building From Source Code with QtCreator in Windows 10 - Flex Dependency

Tags: qgis, c++, qt, flex, build

My end objective is to develop QGIS plugins using C++ for a Windows 10 target machine, and to use QtCreator as the software development and build environment.

Following https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/developers_guide/qtcreator.html
I have downloaded/cloned (forked) a copy of the QGIS source code from Git.
I want to build the QGIS source using QtCreator on Windows 10 and produce a Windows 10 executable.
The above help page shows a linux build environment.
When I open my project in QtCreator (by opening the CMakeLists.txt file), QtCreator parses the project directory and gives me 3 errors, the first is that it cannot find the dependency Flex, I have down loaded flex and bison, and have a win_flex.exe and win_bison.exe executables.

I am using QtCreator 7.0.2 and need to know how to tell it where to find flex, and/or where I need to put the win_flex.exe file, or anything else I need to do to get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this over at the Qt Forum , where we are making progress with answers. The key is knowing what CMake does and how to interpret the CMakeLists.txt file and other CMake files. Hopefully we will get to the end and have some good instructions for how to build QGIS.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/137702/project-configuration-flex-dependency/6